# error: hd0, 1 read error, VM can't boot up

Tags: grub2, virtualbox, virtualization, grubrescue

On Lubuntu 13.10 I had some virtual machines running in VirtualBox 4.2.26. While backing up, all I ever did was make a copy of VirtualBox VMs folder.

I have now switched to OS X, and now I can easily import my VMs, by just copy them out of my backup into the new VirtualBox VMs folder and then go in and manually open the VMNAME.vbox file in each VM folder.

After my BackTrack 5 disco inside VirtualBox lights up, message I get is:

```
error: hd0, 1 read error.
grub rescue> _
```

I have prompt ready to take some commands.

Answer (score 0):

boot a Live CD and reinstall grub2 by chroot'ing to the 'broken' system.

- Boot into Live CD
- Open Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
- Enter the following commands:

  sudo fdisk -l

**And find your Ubuntu partition (should be /dev/sda1 if it is the first partition)**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo chroot /mnt
```

- Now reinstall Grub2

  sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub2